# Lockbox 3 - Reset when not initialized

Tags: delphi, encryption, openssl, rsa, lockbox-3

i am using Windows 8 64-Bit, Delphi XE7 and

so i started to do an own "demo" application to understand how does it work and i got also stucked when i try to decrypt the encrypted string from a memo.

[image]
[image]

Keygeneration

```
procedure TMainForm.Generate_RSA_Keys;
var
  Signatory1: TSignatory;
  codecRSA: TCodec;
  CryptographicLibrary1: TCryptographicLibrary;
  msPublic,msPrivate:TMemoryStream;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  //=================ini====================
  codecRSA:=TCodec.Create(nil);
  CryptographicLibrary1:=TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Signatory1:=TSignatory.Create(nil);
  //=============TCodec===================
  codecRSA.CryptoLibrary  := CryptographicLibrary1;
  codecRSA.StreamCipherId := 'native.RSA';
  codecRSA.ChainModeId:= 'native.CBC';
  codecRSA.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 1024;

  //====Signatory1=====================
  Signatory1.Codec :=codecRSA;

  //==========Save Keys==================
  msPublic:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  msPrivate:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  if Signatory1.GenerateKeys then
  begin
    Signatory1.StoreKeysToStream(msPublic,[partPublic]);
    Signatory1.StoreKeysToStream(msPrivate,[partPrivate]);
    msPublic.SaveToFile(Keypath + PublicKey);
    msPrivate.SaveToFile(Keypath + PrivateKey);
  end;
  msPublic.Free;
  msPrivate.Free;
  codecRSA.Free;
  CryptographicLibrary1.Free;
  Signatory1.Free;
end;
```

Encrypt

```
Call
  EncryptMemoOutput.Lines.Add(EncryptRSA_String(EncryptMemoInput.Text));
```

Procedure

```
function TMainForm.EncryptRSA_String(str:string):String;
var
  Signatory1: TSignatory;
  codecRSA: TCodec;
  CryptographicLibrary1: TCryptographicLibrary;
  ms:TMemoryStream;
  base64Ciphertext: string;
begin
  Result :='';
  //=================ini====================
  codecRSA:=TCodec.Create(nil);
  CryptographicLibrary1:=TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Signatory1:=TSignatory.Create(nil);
  //=============TCodec===================
  codecRSA.CryptoLibrary  := CryptographicLibrary1;
  codecRSA.StreamCipherId := 'native.RSA';
  codecRSA.ChainModeId:= 'native.CBC';
  codecRSA.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 1024;

  //====Signatory1=====================
  Signatory1.Codec :=codecRSA;
  //===Load public key=============
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  ms.LoadFromFile(Keypath + PublicKey);
  Signatory1.LoadKeysFromStream(ms,[partPublic]);
  codecRSA.EncryptString( str, base64Ciphertext);
  codecRSA.EncryptUtf8string( str, base64Ciphertext);
  Result := base64Ciphertext;
  //==free===========
  ms.Free;
  codecRSA.Free;
  CryptographicLibrary1.Free;
  Signatory1.Free;
end;
```

Decrypt (The exception "TSimpleCodec.Init  Reset when not initalized" throws at line   codec.DecryptString(str, base64Ciphertext); )

```
function  TMainForm.DecryptRSA_String(str:String):string ;
var
  ms:TMemoryStream;
  base64Ciphertext: String;
begin
  Result :='';
  codec.Reset;
  //===Load public key=============
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  ms.LoadFromFile(Keypath + PrivateKey);
  Signatory.LoadKeysFromStream(ms,[partPrivate]);
  codec.DecryptString(str, base64Ciphertext);
  Result := base64Ciphertext;

  //==free===========
  ms.Free;
end;
```

So what i am doing wrong? I also tried to use "visual" components instead of creating them at runtime like its done in the encrypt procedure.

====================================================================

## UPDATE MON 10.08.2015

When i load the keys private and public trough this code its working

```
procedure TMainForm.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Store: TStream;
  sRSAKeyFileName, Plain, a: String;
  sPlaintext, sReconstructedPlaintext: string;
  base64Ciphertext: String;
begin
  sRSAKeyFileName := 'C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\Dateien\Development\OpenSSL\Delphi\Win32\Debug\Keys\Lockbox.key';
  Store := TFileStream.Create( sRSAKeyFileName, fmOpenRead);
try
  Store.Position := 0;
  Signatory.LoadKeysFromStream( Store, [partPublic, partPrivate]);

  sPlainText := 'I love LockBox 3!';
  codec.EncryptString( sPlaintext, base64Ciphertext);
  codec.DecryptString( sReconstructedPlaintext, base64Ciphertext);
  ShowMessage(base64Ciphertext + #13#10 + sReconstructedPlaintext);
finally
  Store.Free
  end
end;
```

When i try to load keys serpatley because which i saved seperatly too it doesnt work

```
procedure TMainForm.btEncryptClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  g, f: TFileStream;
  s: String;
begin
  g := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\Dateien\Development\OpenSSL\Delphi\Win32\Debug\Keys\public.key', fmOpenRead); //openssl key
  g.Position := 0;
  Signatory.LoadKeysFromStream(g, [partPublic]);

  s := EncryptMemoInput.Text;
  codec.EncryptString(s, sCryped);
  EncryptMemoOutput.lines.Add(sCryped);

  codec.Reset;

  f := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\Dateien\Development\OpenSSL\Delphi\Win32\Debug\Keys\private.key', fmOpenRead);
  Signatory.LoadKeysFromStream(f, [partPrivate]);
  codec.EncryptString(sUncrypted, sCryped);
  ShowMessage(sUncrypted);


  g.Free;
  f.Free;
end;
```

Encrypt a String does work, encrypt not it throws "TSimpleCodec.Init - Reset when not initalized."

Raised when i call "codec.EncryptString(sUncrypted, sCryped);"

And when i close the application it throws "TSimpleCodec.Init - Cannot set Cipher whilst enc/decrypting"

Comment: *E2037 Declaration of 'Encrypt' differs from previous declaration*: is there another Encrypt funtion somewhere? Ctrl-Click on it to see where that leads you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Polymorphin/df3777292b199310962d

Comment: And i found these 2 Decrypt procedures https://gist.github.com/Polymorphin/47628e34b44e39802a71

Comment: Where did you download the source from?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well the project moved from google code to github so i downloaded it from github. https://github.com/SeanBDurkin/tplockbox

Comment: That doesn't seem to have a .dpr file for the demo. Pretty weird in my view. One thing I cannot understand though is that the error message you quote names `Encrypt`, but there is nothing of that name in the code in the question. How can that be?

Comment: @David That's because he is asking 2 questions.

Comment: Well the main question is how to fix this error "Reset when not initalized" - I started to make a own test application because the one which is bundled in the download archive wasnt compileable and throwed the error "[DCC32 errors] uDemoBlockModeCipher.pas (14): E2037 Declaration of 'Encrypt' differs from previous declaration"

Comment: Your code doesn't use any try/finally and has that odd looking call to ProcessMessages. Your code needlessly uses memory streams instead of file streams. Did you copy all of that from the lockbox code? Personally I think I'd be inclined to get the true demo to compile, but you don't seem to be asking about that.

Comment: I tried to use file streams but they dont have any load/save from/to file routines...The only code i copied from lockbox official code where pasted in the 2 gist links :)

Comment: No they don't.  Why would they?  Simply create a file stream and pass it to the lock box function that expects a stream.  This is quite a complex library. Without a really sound grounding in the language and library basics, you are going to struggle.

Comment: Of course its a complex library but we are talking about too much off topic. I will update my question in a few minutes

Comment: Can you [edit] again and reduce the screenshots by at least half? To start, you should **never** post screen shots of any code - that's what the copy/paste functionality of your OS is for. Screen shots of code are worthless - they're hard to read, the code can't be copied/pasted for testing, and they accomplish nothing but wasting space for people who have to pay for data. Images should only be used when there is no alternative for explaining the problem, and IMO none of them were necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

TurboPower LockBox 3 (v3.6.2.0 from https://github.com/SeanBDurkin/tplockbox) comes with a demo program that does **some** what you are trying to do in this question. Refer to the program "LockBox3_Demo.exe", tabs "4. RSA - Key generation and storage" and "5. RSA - Signature & Verification".

I cleaned up your posted code a little bit in the following listing. This works for me (XE7, Win32, DEBUG). Call Button1Click() to run the round-trip test of RSA encryption/decryption.

## A solution

```
uses TPLB3.CryptographicLibrary, TPLB3.Signatory, TPLB3.Codec,
     TPLB3.Asymetric;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure Generate_RSA_Keys( var msPublic, msPrivate: TMemoryStream);
var
  Signatory1: TSignatory;
  codecRSA: TCodec;
  CryptographicLibrary1: TCryptographicLibrary;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  //=================ini====================
  codecRSA:=TCodec.Create(nil);
  CryptographicLibrary1:=TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Signatory1:=TSignatory.Create(nil);
  //=============TCodec===================
  codecRSA.CryptoLibrary  := CryptographicLibrary1;
  codecRSA.StreamCipherId := 'native.RSA';
  codecRSA.ChainModeId:= 'native.CBC';
  codecRSA.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 1024;

  //====Signatory1=====================
  Signatory1.Codec :=codecRSA;

  //==========Save Keys==================
  msPublic:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  msPrivate:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  if Signatory1.GenerateKeys then
  begin
    Signatory1.StoreKeysToStream(msPublic,[partPublic]);
    Signatory1.StoreKeysToStream(msPrivate,[partPrivate]);
    msPublic.Position := 0;
    msPrivate.Position := 0;
  end;
  codecRSA.Free;
  CryptographicLibrary1.Free;
  Signatory1.Free;
end;


function EncryptRSA_String( const str:string; msPublic: TMemoryStream): string;
var
  Signatory1: TSignatory;
  codecRSA: TCodec;
  CryptographicLibrary1: TCryptographicLibrary;
  base64Ciphertext: string;
begin
  Result :='';
  //=================ini====================
  codecRSA :=TCodec.Create(nil);
  CryptographicLibrary1 := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Signatory1 :=TSignatory.Create(nil);
  //=============TCodec===================
  codecRSA.CryptoLibrary  := CryptographicLibrary1;
  codecRSA.StreamCipherId := 'native.RSA';
  codecRSA.ChainModeId:= 'native.CBC';
  codecRSA.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 1024;

  //====Signatory1=====================
  Signatory1.Codec :=codecRSA;
  //===Load public key=============
  Signatory1.LoadKeysFromStream( msPublic, [partPublic]);
  msPublic.Position := 0;
  codecRSA.EncryptString( str, base64Ciphertext, TEncoding.UTF8);
  Result := base64Ciphertext;
  //==free===========
  codecRSA.Free;
  CryptographicLibrary1.Free;
  Signatory1.Free;
end;


function DecryptRSA_String( const base64Ciphertext: string; const msPublic, msPrivate: TMemoryStream): string ;
var
  Signatory1: TSignatory;
  codecRSA: TCodec;
  CryptographicLibrary1: TCryptographicLibrary;
begin
  Result :='';
  //=================ini====================
  codecRSA :=TCodec.Create(nil);
  CryptographicLibrary1 := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Signatory1 :=TSignatory.Create(nil);
  //=============TCodec===================
  codecRSA.CryptoLibrary  := CryptographicLibrary1;
  codecRSA.StreamCipherId := 'native.RSA';
  codecRSA.ChainModeId:= 'native.CBC';
  codecRSA.AsymetricKeySizeInBits := 1024;

  //====Signatory1=====================
  Signatory1.Codec :=codecRSA;
  Signatory1.LoadKeysFromStream( msPrivate,[partPrivate]);
  codecRSA.DecryptString( result, base64Ciphertext, TEncoding.UTF8);

  //==free===========
  codecRSA.Free;
  CryptographicLibrary1.Free;
  Signatory1.Free;
end;


procedure TForm27.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  msPublic,msPrivate: TMemoryStream;
  PlainText: string;
  CipherText: string;
  Recon: string;
begin
  PlainText := 'Some text';
  Generate_RSA_Keys( msPublic,msPrivate);
  CipherText := EncryptRSA_String( PlainText, msPublic);
  Recon      := DecryptRSA_String( CipherText, msPublic, msPrivate);
  msPublic.Free;
  msPrivate.Free;
  if Recon = PlainText then
      ShowMessage( 'PASS')
    else
      ShowMessage( 'FAIL')
end;
```

## What was wrong with the OP code?

The OP does not show the outer level code which was calling DecryptRSA_String(). I am guessing that he called DecryptRSA_String() with an empty actual parameter value for `str`. This would throw that `TSimpleCodec.Init Reset when not initalized` exception.

Comment: Thanks for this answer sean, can you tell me how do i load a public/private key into -> Signatory1.LoadKeysFromStream when the keys exist as file on my harddrive and are not generated by my program itself ?

Comment: @Hidden: Open a file stream and load it.

Comment: Well now i cant load it to the stream. It always saying "Stream error".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853481/lockbox-3-load-public-key-not-possible-stream-reading-error

Comment: It looks like chadkops and Uwe Raabe have answered your question.

Comment: As i answered to him it did not make any effect - same error

Comment: @Hidden: Can you post your updated code, the exact error message, and the point at which it is raised. No screen-shots please.

Comment: @Hidden: With asymetric ciphers such as RSA, the cipher requires the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption. (Also Signature operation requires private key, and Verify requires public key.)

When you loaded the private key, it blew away the public key, which meant that the codec was not initialised for encryption. Probably you intended that second Codec.EncryptString() to be Codec.DecryptString().