# Delphi LockBox3, Asymetric_Engine.createFromStream error

Tags: delphi, rsa, lockbox-3

EDIT: because i couldn't get this code to work, i did an little workaround: now i call openssl console via ShellExecute (not much safe, but it works).

Good morning all, i'm getting an headache to get this delphi code work:

```
(included uTPLb_* libraries)
function Crypto.encodeRSA(msg:String;test:Boolean = False):String;
  var
    file_path:String;
    keyStream:TMemoryStream;
    res:String;
    Codec:TCodec;
    wasAborted:Boolean;
    KeyPair:TAsymetricKeyPair;
    Key:TSymetricKey;
    lib:TCryptographicLibrary;
    signatory:TSignatory;
  begin
    codec:=TCodec.Create(nil);
    signatory:=TSignatory.Create(nil);
    lib:=TCryptoGraphicLibrary.Create(nil);
    try
     if test then
        begin
          file_path:=PUBLIC_KEY_TEST_FILE;
        end
      else
        begin
          file_path:=PUBLIC_KEY_FILE;
        end;
      file_path:=GetCurrentDir+'\'+file_path;
      keyStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
      keyStream.LoadFromFile(file_path);

      codec.Reset;
      codec.CryptoLibrary:=lib;
      codec.ChainModeId:=ECB_ProgID;
      codec.StreamCipherId:='native.RSA';
      Codec.StreamCipherId:=RSA_ProgID;

      signatory.Codec:=codec;
      signatory.LoadKeysFromStream(keyStream,[partPublic]);


      //stuff to do...
      Result:=res;

    finally
      lib.Free;
      codec.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

The problem is "signatory.LoadKeysFromStream(keyStream,[partPublic]);" procedure continue to fail with "Stream Error" exception; file is correctly open in reading mode.

Content of the public key file is

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsU4LA0ZLWO+twuoReM41
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

(i have full key, but i prefer not divulgate)

Does anyone can help me?
I read about pkcs#1 padding and openssl command
([Lockbox 3 load public key not possible - stream reading error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853481/lockbox-3-load-public-key-not-possible-stream-reading-error))

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in yourpublickey -RSAPublicKey_out -out publicpkcs1
```

but "-RSAPublicKey_out" isn't recognized (OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016).
I have also private key.

Thanks to all which can help me!

update:
i tried also generating cryptographic keys, but i cannot read them.

```
signatory.storeKeysToStream
```

the result is the same.

I downloaded library here:
https://github.com/TurboPack/LockBox

Comment: LockBox3 is not compatible with OpenSSL. OpenSSL 0.9.8 is old and buggy. Use latest version (1.0.x)

Comment: i run this application with 1.0.2h version, thank you for the suggestion.